# Security patches for Kubernetes Nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I have access to a kops-built kubernetes cluster on AWS EC2 instances. I would like to make sure, that all available security patches from the corresponding package manager are applied. Unfortunately searching the whole internet for hours I am unable to find any clue on how this should be done. Taking a look into the user data of the launch configurations I did not find a line for the package manager - Therefor I am not sure if a simple node restart will do the trick and I also want to make sure that new nodes come up with current packages.

How to make security patches on upcoming nodes of a kubernetes cluster and how to make sure that all nodes are and stay up-to-date?

Comment: After some more googling a came around a "workaround" - I could define my own scripts for this job as additional user data script. But that more feels unnatural for such an essential problem. There must be information or structured ways for this :/ https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/instance_groups.md#additional-user-data-for-cloud-init

Answer (score 1):

You might want to explore https://github.com/weaveworks/kured

Kured (KUbernetes REboot Daemon) is a Kubernetes daemonset that performs safe automatic node reboots when the need to do so is indicated by the package management system of the underlying OS.

Watches for the presence of a reboot sentinel e.g. /var/run/reboot-required
Utilises a lock in the API server to ensure only one node reboots at a time
Optionally defers reboots in the presence of active Prometheus alerts or selected pods
Cordons & drains worker nodes before reboot, uncordoning them after